# How to verify files installed in system against 3rdparty deb package?

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, security, deb

I'm aware about `dpkg -V` and `debsums`, but I need to check installed files against given deb files, not metadata stored in system.

Comment: File-by-file hash list. Where file on left side is one installed in the system and file on right side is one from the given deb package file.

Comment: Why not tell us what the real problem is? Maybe we have a better solution.

Comment: This is a real problem, I have a machine with Ubuntu and software installed from 3rdparty deb package, I have said deb package on hands, I need to check if files installed in the system as part of package mentioned above byte-to-byte identical with reference deb.

Comment: I understand that... but why do you feel the need to do that? Is there a problem with that 3rd party software, or with the system in general? I ask these questions so that I can come up with the best answer.

Comment: I need to prove files from 3rd party deb package was unchanged after they installed while the system itself was untrusted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dpkg-deb -x` to open a package, generate a list of hashes to check, and then verify them:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/bat
$ cd /tmp
$ dpkg-deb -x /var/cache/apt/archives/bat_0.12.1-1build1_amd64.deb bat
$ cd bat
$ find . -type f -exec sha256sum '{}' + > /tmp/sums
$ cd /
$ sha256sum -c /tmp/sums 
./usr/share/man/man1/batcat.1.gz: OK
./usr/share/doc/bat/README.Debian: OK
./usr/share/doc/bat/changelog.Debian.gz: OK
./usr/share/doc/bat/copyright: OK
./usr/share/lintian/overrides/bat: OK
./usr/bin/batcat: OK
./usr/.crates2.json: OK
$
```

I don't know what problem you're trying to solve, though; installing new .deb packages requires full root privileges, the maintainer scripts provided by the package run with unconfined root privileges. If you strictly want to verify that the files in the package match what's on disk, this can do that, but it can't do much else.